# How do I uninstall/remove drivers for a iphone?

Tags: drivers, uninstall, iphone, reinstalling

OK..I have iphone that doesn't connect to my ubuntu as it should. I want to remove and reinstall its drivers that are automatically installed upon plugging in. How do I completely remove the drivers so that they will be installed again and iphone will seem to be connected the first time?

Comment: someone should help!